Having issues with Gopls in Nvim also with other Lsp's
I have an issue with LSP gopls in nvim that sometimes gopls doesnt identify newly created functions when i am working in with big go projects why?
The thing is i need to entirely close and reopen nvim or entering :LspRestart command for gopls to identify the newly created functions or packages. This happens specifically when i work with somewhat big Go projects with some or many interfaces. why this stuff happening is there any way to make the gopls instantly identifying the changes i made in directory. There is a lag everytime :???
If anyone faced similar issues with their nvim lsp like this can u guys help me.

I think the problem is with Golang's language server (gopls) rather than Neovim itself. Most language servers tend to perform slowly when working with large projects. Try enabling logging on gopls (-logfile=string) to debug.

Also set vim.lsp.set_log_level(vim.log.levels.DEBUG) and check:LspLog

Thnks for the reply ill check into that
